# Site looks good locally in Firefox 29.0.1 but not remotely

Tags: firefox, localhost, html5-video

A site I am working on: http://ninthmind.com, looks good remotely in all browsers except Firefox 29.0.1. I have cleared my cached and searched for syntax errors. The weird thing is it looks as expected locally on my machine in the same Firefox browser.

There is a video element within the site that is also not appearing (only remotely in firefox) despite having both mp4 and webm sources. In the code below the class "invis" changes the mask's and the video's display to none for mobile devices.

```
<div class="header">
        <img class="invis" id="mask" src="images/mask.png">
        <video class="invis" id="brain" autoplay loop>
            <source src="video/brain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="video/brain.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
        <div class="welcome">
            <h1>Welcome to</h1>
            <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <h3>subheading</h3>
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That webm file is being served with the wrong mime type. It should be "video/webm" but it's being served as "text/plain". You probably have this set up correctly on your local machine (or you're using "file://") but not the remote server.

These instructions should help you:
http://voice.firefallpro.com/2012/03/html5-audio-video-mime-types.html